# Extruding snaps back

Tags: modeling

I'm using blender 2.8 for over 2 weeks now.

If I extrude a face, it snaps back into place. But only when the extrusion is under 0.200 meters.

I did check the "snapping" setting, but its not that.

Comment: Do you have Auto Merge active in the edit mode options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have automerge turned on, or with a too high threshold.

Turn it off or reduce the threshold in the *Tool* tab of the 3D Viewport sidebar

[image]

Comment: Omg, thanks so much. I have searched like 50 percent of the internet for this .